# Why is arcpy.CalculateField_management() writing 1899-12-30 00:00:00 instead of expected date?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, date, error-000539, datetime

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop to test before writing an answer to [Entering date with arcpy.GetParameterAsText()?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151095/how-to-enter-date-with-arcpy-getparameterastext-with-arcpy) I have written the test code below that I am running against a test feature class (`testFC`) with four line features to try and update its `dateField` with a constant date value of "01.07.2015".

```
import arcpy

dmyString = "01.07.2015"
fc = r"C:\temp\test.gdb\testFC"
item = "dateField"

dmyDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(dmyString,'%d.%m.%Y')
print dmyDate

arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc,item,dmyDate,"PYTHON")

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,[item]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print row[0]
```

I think the above should work, and from the output below you can see that the date object (`dmyDate`) seems to be created fine, but the values written to each of the four features are not what I would expect.

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
2015-07-01 00:00:00
1899-12-30 00:00:00
1899-12-30 00:00:00
1899-12-30 00:00:00
1899-12-30 00:00:00
>>>
```

Can someone explain why `1899-12-30 00:00:00` is being written instead of `2015-07-01 00:00:00`?

The attribute table displays as below:

[image]

If I replace the CalculateField line above with either:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc,item,"date '2015-07-01 00:00:00'","PYTHON")
```

or

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc,item,"date '2015/07/01 00:00:00'","PYTHON")
```

as per @Vince's comments I receive an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\temp\test.py", line 11, in <module>
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc,item,"date '2015-07-01 00:00:00'","PYTHON")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 3457, in CalculateField
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000539: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<expression>, line 1)
Failed to execute (CalculateField).
```

Comment: By chance, is there a selection on the feature class, so that only one value is updated? What values display in the attribute table?

Comment: Since the date is mapping to a "-1" of the epoch, it seems that your datetime object is not accepted as input to the `expression` parameter. Have you tried using a string value, formatted "date 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'" or "date 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS'"?

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s500000033000000), the '1899/12/30' date is the epoch in ArcGIS, and both `date '2015-07-01'` and `date '2015-07-01 00:00:00'` should be valid  with FGDB sources.  Having the date formatting fail silently like that is, IMHO, a bug which should be fixed.

Comment: @Vince, that is SQL syntax..it's not supposed to work for FieldCalc (take a look at the top of the page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below demonstrates how to get this to work using code very similar to that in the question, but I recommend also reviewing the detailed explanation that follows in order to understand why it works:

```
import arcpy

dmyString = "01.07.2015"
d,m,Y = dmyString.split(".")
dmyDate = datetime.datetime(int(Y),int(m),int(d))
epoch = datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30)
days = (dmyDate - epoch).days

fc = r"C:\temp\test.gdb\testFC"
item = "dateField"

print dmyDate

arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc,item,days,"PYTHON")

print "\nOutput:"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,[item]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print row[0]
```

produces:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
2015-07-01 00:00:00

Output:
2015-07-01 00:00:00
2015-07-01 00:00:00
2015-07-01 00:00:00
2015-07-01 00:00:00
>>>
```

[image]

Don't be disturbed that you see 1/07/2015 (instead of 7/01/2015) above - PolyGeo's Windows settings are for Australia where they tend to use dd/mm/YYYY.

### Why it works:

Alright, so CalculateField is expecting a the number of days since the epoch (1899-12-30 as @Vince pointed out) whereas UpdateCursor accepts either a datetime.datetime() object or delta days.

```
import arcpy, time
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\testing.gdb"

def compare(calc, cursor):
    #Create new fields
    arcpy.DeleteField_management("dater", ["date1", "date2"])
    arcpy.AddField_management("dater", "date1", "DATE")
    arcpy.AddField_management("dater", "date2", "DATE")

    #Let's try CalcField
    arcpy.CalculateField_management("dater", "date1", calc, "PYTHON")

    #And now Ucursor
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("dater", ["date2"]) as rows:
        for row in rows:
            rows.updateRow([cursor])

    #Let's take a look.....
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("dater", ["date1", "date2"]) as rows:
        for row in rows:        
            print("Calc:\t{}\tUcursor:\t{}".format(*row))


date1 = datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 10)
#Days since the epoch            
epoch = datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30)
days = (date1 - epoch).days

print("Datetime to both:\n")
compare(date1, date1)
print("\nDelta days to calc, datetime to Ucursor:\n")
compare(days, date1)
print("\nDelta days to both::\n")
compare(days, days)
```

The Result:

```
Datetime to both:

Calc:   1899-12-30 00:00:00 Ucursor:    2015-07-10 00:00:00
Calc:   1899-12-30 00:00:00 Ucursor:    2015-07-10 00:00:00
Calc:   1899-12-30 00:00:00 Ucursor:    2015-07-10 00:00:00

Delta days to calc, datetime to Ucursor:

Calc:   2015-07-10 00:00:00 Ucursor:    2015-07-10 00:00:00
Calc:   2015-07-10 00:00:00 Ucursor:    2015-07-10 00:00:00
Calc:   2015-07-10 00:00:00 Ucursor:    2015-07-10 00:00:00

Delta days to both::

Calc:   2015-07-10 00:00:00 Ucursor:    2015-07-10 00:00:00
Calc:   2015-07-10 00:00:00 Ucursor:    2015-07-10 00:00:00
Calc:   2015-07-10 00:00:00 Ucursor:    2015-07-10 00:00:00
```

Very interesting stuff! Clearly, cursors are the preferred choice when dealing with dates. That or the `VBScript` parser for FieldCalc.

Comment: Thanks, but that's a workaround that I know works, because I normally use cursors to do this.  It was the question I linked to, and [this duplicate of that](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153963/difficulty-populating-date-field-with-arcpy) that led my to trying to run a test to demonstrate how to do it with CalculateField.  +1 for some useful code that I am sure future visitors will benefit from.

Comment: @PolyGeo, if you really want to scratch your head, try entering `time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")` into FieldCalculator...it returns `1900-01-27 00:00:00` interestingly enough.

Comment: @PolyGeo, the "random" 1900 date is what helped me figure it out. I started passing incrementing numbers to FieldCalc and watched the date increase.

Comment: That's awesome Paul - I hope you don't mind that I added in the test code I used to verify what you say into your answer. I think this Q&A will be visited by people who may not be able to go from your "proof" to getting their code working.  I was worried that my question may have indicated something obvious that I was overlooking and very glad to have you, @Vince and recurvata take part in the challenge of how to answer it.

Comment: @PolyGeo, by all means! I edited yours slightly so that it's a bit simpler to see the difference between `dmyDate` and the output from the cursor.